# Linear Law Problem.

Tags: logarithms

```
Q: A law of the form y=abx relates x and y.
From a set of readings, lg y is plotted against x to give a
straight line with gradient and vertical intercept both 1.5 each.
Deduce the value of a and b.
```

```
ANS; a = 120 
   ; b = 10
```

I've tried putting lg on both sides for y=ab$^x$ and got: lg y = lg a + x lg b. I guess y-intercept = lg a and gradient = lg b ?
Also, I tried comparing:

```
lg y - 1.5x - 1.5 == lg y - lg a - (lg b)x
```

I can't get further.

**Actually the solutions are wrong, some error occured. The answers for a and b are ;lg a = 1.5; & ;lg b = 1.5;**

Comment: That's exactly it.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done the correct thing in taking logarithms. We have $$\ln y = \ln a + x\ln b.$$ (Note that any logarithm base will do, but just run with this.) We're given that the slope (gradient) is $1.5$. So $\ln b = 1.5$. The y-intercept is also given so $\ln a = 1.5$. The result follows.

I'm not sure why the answer key gives the answers as such. It is possible it could be a typographical error.